# Cannot get small app to spin up a single instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a small python app deployed to app engine. It worked fine for a few days, but today it was unreachable. Now the dev. console shows that there are no instances of the app running.  If I try to launch the app or request some data from it it will not spin up a new instance.

I've tried increasing the version number and redeploying. No issues deploying the app. I see my new version, but still not instances of the app are running.

Is there a manual way to spin up an instance?

Comment: Normally it's via sending a request to the app. There's NOTHING in your logs about your request?

Comment: Now it's back up. I didn't try anything else that I didn't earlier. There were no logs from the time it was down. Now everything is logging as expected.